# order in stl queue container

Tags: c++, queue

I'm trying to make a queue of a class that uses a template, but when I try to use the functions front or back I get an error saying that the operator "<<" doesn't match the function. But if I use the function size, for example, it works fine. So, I was wondering that maybe it is because of the order in objects in the queue? I already tried to overload the << operator but didn't work. Thanks for any help.
Here's my code:

```
//STL queue container
queue<stackType<int>> stack5;

stack5.push(5);
stack5.push(8);
stack5.push(6);

cout << "The front element of stack5 is: " << stack5.front() << endl;
```

Comment: What is a `stackType<int>`?

Comment: It's a class that uses a template.

Comment: Does it have a `operator <<` defined?  Or a conversion operator?  You'll need one of those since `std::cout` doesn't know about your custom type.

Comment: Replace `queue<stackType<int>> stack5;` with `queue<int> stack5;`

Comment: I have to use the class, that's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you mean the standard library's [`<queue>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) and not the legacy STL of the 90's,  your `stack5.front()` is of type `stackType<int>`.

If you use this type with a stream inserter `<<`, it needs to have `ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const stackType<T> &)` defined.

Comment: It has an overloading of the << operator but now doesn't print the right value.

Comment: @Natalia could you edit your question and clarify what « it doesn’t work » really means (e.g. code of the overload, value it prints and value that it expects or error message of the compiler if it’s doesn’t even compile) ? (and answer to this comment when you’ve done it, so that I can look at the additional info)